# Can a spring bean instance variable holds dynamic value ( per request)

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring bean class( OrderUtil) like below which has an instance variable

```
public class OrderUtil {

    private boolean dynamicValue;
public boolean isDynamicValue() {
        return dynamicValue;
    }

    public void setDynamicValue(boolean dynamicValue) {
        this.dynamicValue = dynamicValue;
    }

}
```

I am autowiring this util class in different class

```
public class RestService {

        @Autowired
    private OrderUtil orderUtil;

@POST
    @Path("order/{orderNumber}")
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getOrderDetails( @QueryParam("dynamicValue") boolean dynamicValue){

//some code

orderUtil.setDynamicValue(dynamicValue)

}



}
```

question: The dynamicValue can either come as true/false from the api request. The fact that i am setting this dynamic value true/false to instance variable is bringing up a question in case of multiple requests use case from two customers A ( true value) and B ( false value) at same time.

Wondering if user see any inconsistent behaviour, i.e User B's false value behavior shows up in user A's response ?  Please assist

Comment: I think your question is about bean scopes, read this page in documentation to learn a lot about it: [bean scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html). In short, by default beans are singleton. You probably want to set scope to `request` to have different states per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fact better to use a dynamic variable in the @Service bean with the default scope (singleton).
Your REST component has a request scope.
Also you need to provide a thread save variable, use AtomicBoolean for example

```
@Service
class OrderUtil {
    private static final AtomicBoolean dynamicValue = new AtomicBoolean();

    public boolean isDynamicValue() {
        return dynamicValue.get();
    }

    public void setDynamicValue(boolean v) {
        dynamicValue.set(v);
    }

    //think about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap
    public boolean casDynamicValue(boolean expect, boolean update) {
        return dynamicValue.compareAndSet(expect, update);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is based on Bean scope and can be solved with proper use of beans scopes.

Here Every Rest request comes with a Request Scoped bean and the bean remains active in a given request.

Every request will create its own thread hence there won't be any discrepancies thought by you is possible as every request will have one value of dynamicValue either true/false which will be valid throughout the request session.

you can refer here for proper understanding on Bean Scopes [BeanScopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s05.html).